# Parsing Escaped javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following string which I am trying to parse into a JSON object and then turn into a javascript array:

```
"[{\"items\":\"nut\",\"sales\":6,\"prices\":10},\n {\"items\":\"bolt\",\"sales\":8,\"prices\":20},\n {\"items\":\"cam\",\"sales\":0,\"prices\":15},\n {\"items\":\"cog\",\"sales\":3,\"prices\":20}]"
```

which i remove the newline character to get

```
"{\"items\":\"nut\",\"sales\":6,\"prices\":10}, {\"items\":\"bolt\",\"sales\":8,\"prices\":20}, {\"items\":\"cam\",\"sales\":0,\"prices\":15}, {\"items\":\"cog\",\"sales\":3,\"prices\":20}"
```

I tried this

```
   dd = "[{\"items\":\"nut\",\"sales\":6,\"prices\":10},\n {\"items\":\"bolt\",\"sales\":8,\"prices\":20},\n {\"items\":\"cam\",\"sales\":0,\"prices\":15},\n {\"items\":\"cog\",\"sales\":3,\"prices\":20}]";
   dd = dd.replace(/\\n/g, '');
   dd = dd.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');
   console.log(JSON.parse(dd));
   dd= JSON.parse(dd));
```

But this doesnt actually parse the json for some reason as dd.items is null

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 3):

> But this doesnt actually parse the json for some reason as dd.items is
>   null

There is no need to remove newline `\n` from the string, just directly do `JSON.parse`

```js
var dd = JSON.parse( "[{\"items\":\"nut\",\"sales\":6,\"prices\":10},\n {\"items\":\"bolt\",\"sales\":8,\"prices\":20},\n {\"items\":\"cam\",\"sales\":0,\"prices\":15},\n {\"items\":\"cog\",\"sales\":3,\"prices\":20}]" );
console.log(dd);
```

Also, `dd` is an array so you need to iterate dd to get `items`

```
dd.forEach( s => console.log(s.items) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = "[{\"items\":\"nut\",\"sales\":6,\"prices\":10},\n {\"items\":\"bolt\",\"sales\":8,\"prices\":20},\n {\"items\":\"cam\",\"sales\":0,\"prices\":15},\n {\"items\":\"cog\",\"sales\":3,\"prices\":20}]";
let y = x.substr(1, x.length - 2).split(',\n').map(JSON.parse);
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
   `JSON.parse(dd);` 
function to remove this

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data="[{\"items\":\"nut\",\"sales\":6,\"prices\":10},\n {\"items\":\"bolt\",\"sales\":8,\"prices\":20},\n {\"items\":\"cam\",\"sales\":0,\"prices\":15},\n {\"items\":\"cog\",\"sales\":3,\"prices\":20}]";

//use JSON parse that will convert the string to JSON like array of objects please dont do any modification in the returned string

console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```